# Solving this differential equation via dividing by $t^n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this differential equation that I need to solve:

$y'=\frac{(x^2-y^2)}{3xy}$

My teacher gave a hint to divide everything on the right hand side by $t^n$, but I do not see how this is helpful.  Can anyone give me a hint? Thank you!

Comment: Substitute $y=vx$ where $v$ is a function of $x$. This is the standard method for such homogeneous equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential equation being $$y'=\frac{(x^2-y^2)}{3xy}$$ you can notice that it is perfectly homogeneous and, as David Quinn already commented, define $y=x z$ which makes $y'=z+x z'$. Now replace $$z+x z'=\frac{(x^2-x^2 z^2)}{3x^2z}=\frac{(1-z^2)}{3z}$$ Multiply each side by $3z$ $$3z^2+3xzz'=1-z^2$$ $$4z^2+3xzz'=1$$ that is to say $$4z^2+\frac32 x (2zz')=1$$ $$4z^2+\frac32 x (z^2)'=1$$ So, now $t=z^2$ to get $$4t+\frac32 xt'=1$$ which is now easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

$$3xy y' + y^2 = x^2$$

What would happen if we differentiated $x y^2$? We'd get $y^2 + 2 y y' x$.
So by a bit of magic, we can multiply through by $y$ and observe that the equation is now of the form $$\dfrac{d}{dx} (x y^3) = x^2 y$$

Let $u = x y^3$, so the equation is $$\dfrac{du}{dx} = x^2 y = x^2 (u/x)^{1/3}$$
or
$$\dfrac{du}{dx}= x^{5/3} u^{1/3}$$

This is separable: integrate both sides of $$u^{-1/3} du = x^{5/3} dx$$
so $$\frac{3}{2} u^{2/3} = \frac{3}{8} x^{8/3} + C$$

whence $$\frac{3}{2} (x y^3)^{2/3} = \frac{3}{8} x^{8/3} + C$$
which you can tidy up yourself. (You should strictly check that all values of $C$ do actually give solutions to the original equation, because we might have introduced extra ones along the way.)